# Jackson JSON Handling of Unicode symbols

Tags: java, json, unicode, jackson, utf

I'm calling a webservice that returns text including the ascii symbols representing the ® symbol. For example:

```
ACME Corp® Services
```

I use spring to return this textual data directly as a JSON object, and by the time it gets into the browser the json data remains correct:

```
"service": "ACME Corp® Services"
```

But upon being rendered via a `Handlebars` template and written into the page I get:

```
ACME CorpÂ® Services
```

Do I need to sanitize the `JSON` data before using it? If so, what are the best practices for doing that? Otherwise, perhaps there is a change I should make on the back-end but I am not sure what that would be.

Comment: These links might help: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/110, and http://codrspace.com/durden/dealing-with-special-characters-in-json-and-handlebar-js-template/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need to sanitize content, but you must make sure it uses valid encoding allowed by JSON specification: typically UTF-8 (alternatives being UTF-16 and UTF-32).

If content is not encoded as UTF-8 but something else (like `ISO-8859-1` aka "Latin-1"), you will need to construct `Reader` to decode it properly:

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(in, StandardCharset.ISO_8859_1);
MyPOJO pojo = mapper.readValue(r, MyPOJO.class);
```

Problem you seem to be having is that encoding used is incorrect.